# Unable to replicate due slave_I/O_running:No

Tags: mysql

```
I have a master mysql server 5.5 version and a slave 5.1 version. I am getting the 
following error.
mysql> show slave status\G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           Slave_IO_State: Connecting to master
              Master_Host: XXX.XX.X.XXX
              Master_User: repl_user
              Master_Port: 3306
            Connect_Retry: 60
          Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000012
      Read_Master_Log_Pos: 107
           Relay_Log_File: ABC-029-relay-bin.000001
            Relay_Log_Pos: 4
    Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000012
         Slave_IO_Running: No
        Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
          Replicate_Do_DB: replication_test
      Replicate_Ignore_DB:
       Replicate_Do_Table:
   Replicate_Ignore_Table:
  Replicate_Wild_Do_Table:
 Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table:
               Last_Errno: 0
               Last_Error:
             Skip_Counter: 0
      Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 107
          Relay_Log_Space: 106
          Until_Condition: None
           Until_Log_File:
            Until_Log_Pos: 0
       Master_SSL_Allowed: No
       Master_SSL_CA_File:
       Master_SSL_CA_Path:
          Master_SSL_Cert:
        Master_SSL_Cipher:
           Master_SSL_Key:
    Seconds_Behind_Master: NULL
   Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
            Last_IO_Errno: 1045
            Last_IO_Error: error connecting to master 
  'repl_user@XXX.XX.X.XXX:3306' -     retry-time: 60  retries: 86400
           Last_SQL_Errno: 0
             Last_SQL_Error:
  1 row in set (0.00 sec)
  Please suggest what to do?
```

Comment: I am using windows 7 system for both master and slave

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Error "1045" indicatates a login/credentials issue. Check to see if your login/password is correct or check if your firewall isn't blocking the connection.

Comment: I just got the problem. Actually there is a problem in giving permission to the slave. Initially I had used Grant all on *.* to 'repl_user'@'localhost' identified by 'password'. Then I changed it to 'repl_user'@'%'